# PromiseKit firstly around code, not function call

Tags: swift, promisekit

I don't want to write a separate function to return a Promise in my firstly call. I just want to write this:

```
firstly
{
    return Promise<Bool>
    { inSeal in
        var isOrderHistory = false
        let importTester = CSVImporter<String>(url: url)
        importTester?.startImportingRecords(structure:
            { (inFieldNames) in
                if inFieldNames[2] == "Payment Instrument Type"
                {
                    isOrderHistory = true
                }
            }, recordMapper: { (inRecords) -> String in
                return ""   //  Don't care
            }).onFinish
            { (inItems) in
                inSeal.resolve(isOrderHistory)
            }
    }
}
.then
{ inIsOrderHistory in
    if inIsOrderHistory -> Void
    {
    }
    else
    {
...
```

But I'm getting something wrong. `ImportMainWindowController.swift:51:5: Ambiguous reference to member 'firstly(execute:)'`

None of the example code or docs seems to cover this (what I thought was a) basic use case. In the code above, the CSVImporter operates on a background queue and calls the methods asynchronously (although in order).

I can't figure out what the full type specification should be for `Promise` or `firstly`, or what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my understanding, since you are using `then` in the promise chain, it is also meant to return a promise and hence you are getting this error. If you intend not to return promise from your next step, you can directly use `done` after firstly.

Use below chain if you want to return Promise from `then`

```
firstly {
     Promise<Bool> { seal in
        print("hello")
        seal.fulfill(true)
     }
}.then { (response) in
    Promise<Bool> { seal in
            print(response)
            seal.fulfill(true)
    }
}.done { _ in
    print("done")
}.catch { (error) in
        print(error)
}
```

If you do not want to return Promise from `then`, you can use chain like below.

```
firstly {
            Promise<Bool> { seal in
                print("hello")
                seal.fulfill(true)
            }
        }.done { _ in
                print("done")
        }.catch { (error) in
                print(error)
        }
```

I hope it helped.

**Updated:**

In case you do not want to return anything and `then` mandates to return a `Promise`, you can return `Promise<Void>` like below.

```
firstly {
    Promise<Bool> { seal in
        print("hello")
        seal.fulfill(true)
    }
}.then { (response) -> Promise<Void> in
            print(response)
            return Promise()
}.done { _ in
        print("done")
}.catch { (error) in
        print(error)
}
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the issue. But now I'm finding I really do want a `.then` that returns nothing, because I want the semantic clarity of doing something else in the `.done` section. The `.then` sets a property on the object. Obviously it can return that result instead, but it seems like I should be able to have `.then` that don't return anything. Maybe I'm just being picky?

Comment: You can use a Promise<Void>. I have updated the answer. I hope this helps